# Can not find symbol using array sort with user input

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

beginner - This is passed due homework. I am suppose to eliminate duplicate numbers and given the specific public static int[] xxx(int[] list) to be used. The following code gives me error when I compile in textpad cannot find symbol number[i] and ^ is at [i].symbol vaiable i(couldn't copy error msg)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Duplicate{

public static int[] Duplicate(int[] list){

int[] numbers = new int[10];

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers: ");
numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
Arrays.sort(numbers);

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
System.out.println(numbers[i]);


}//end eliminate
}//end Duplicate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have switched around the line with the loop header and the loop body:

```
numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Currently, your code uses `i` before it gets declared, and sorts ten times; neither of these two things makes sense.

A very good habit to learn early on is placing curly braces around bodies of all control statements, even when the body is a single line. This would help you avoid simple errors like that by visually pairing control structures with the code that they control.

Comment: Thank you.  That does make sense.  Question for you.  when I do change the code, it then tells me that I need a return statement.  is it because it is expecting an int return?

Comment: @Lish Yes, any function that is declared with a non-`void` return type must have at least one `return` statement in their body. You may have multiple returns, but each way through the code must end in a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables before you use them.

```
numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
```

In the above line in your code, i has not been initialized and hence you are getting this error.